# Boost::Asio - Passing socket to second class

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am currently trying to get the following application to work:

1. Await incoming client connection.
2. Start async. timer in another class.
3. While the timer runs repeatedly, do other stuff such as `async_read` and `async_write`.

**Current source code**:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Mswsock.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "TimerClass.hpp"

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

TimerClass *timerClass;

void acceptHandler(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, tcp::socket *socket) {
    timerClass = new TimerClass(socket);
    timerClass->startTimer();
    while(true) {
        // Do other suff such as async_write, ...
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    io_service ioService;
    tcp::socket socket(ioService);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor{ ioService, tcp::endpoint{ tcp::v4(), 12345 } };
    acceptor.listen();
    acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(acceptHandler, _1, &socket));
    ioService.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**TimerClass.hpp**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

class TimerClass {
public:
    TimerClass(ip::tcp::socket *socket);
    void startTimer();
    void timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode);
    deadline_timer timer;
};
```

**TimerClass.cpp**:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "TimerClass.hpp"

TimerClass::TimerClass(ip::tcp::socket *socket) : timer(socket->get_io_service(), boost::posix_time::seconds(1)) {}

void TimerClass::startTimer() {
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerClass::timerHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void TimerClass::timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode) {
    timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerClass::timerHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

**Handler Tracking Output**:

```
@asio|1461070492.111630|0*1|socket@000000000021FBD0.async_accept
@asio|1461070498.527997|>1|ec=system:0
```

**Questions**:

1. Why won't it even call `async_wait` in `startTimer`? Debugging shows that `startTimer` gets called but I can't find anything in the Handler Tracking output. Why is that?
2. Am I correctly passing the socket to the TimerClass?
3. Without the infinite while(true) loop in the acceptHandler the acceptHandler returns but the application crashes before the io_service properly returns. How is that?

Comment: I compiled your code and I actually see a call to `async_wait`. Which boost version are you using (tried on 1.54). Handler tracking output: `@asio|1461081908.437388|0*1|socket@003BFE2C.async_accept
@asio|1461081983.220840|>1|ec=system:0
@asio|1461081983.221817|1*2|deadline_timer@001C1318.async_wait`

Comment: @Nacho I'm using version 1.59.0 - Does the timer actually work in your execution? It should be executed every second.

Comment: Yes actually, I had to remove the `while(true)` though. Oh, I know what might be the problem. Do you have include guards on your `TimerClass.hpp`?

Comment: @Nacho Check my third question on the very bottom of my original post. My application crashes when I remove the while(true). async_wait doesn't get called though. The acceptHandler returns before that (`@asio|1461083049.697883|0*1|socket@00000000002CFC80.async_accept
@asio|1461083052.420039|>1|ec=system:0
@asio|1461083052.421039|<1|`)

Comment: @Nacho I have the same behaviour with #pragma once at the very top in the header file.

Comment: @Nacho Hmmm ... I've just moved the implementations of the functions in the .hpp file directly. That way it showed async_wait in the Handler Tracking output. How is that?

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your code and it works for me (using boost version 1.54).

With your code I get the following output:

```
@asio|1461081908.437388|0*1|socket@003BFE2C.async_accept 
@asio|1461081983.220840|>1|ec=system:0    
@asio|1461081983.221817|1*2|deadline_timer@001C1318.async_wait
```

To make it run properly I had to remove the `while(true)` on your `acceptHandler`, obtaining the following output (added a `std::cout` inside the handler):

```
@asio|1461083707.104424|0*1|socket@0030FB6C.async_accept
@asio|1461083709.061824|>1|ec=system:0
@asio|1461083709.062803|1*2|deadline_timer@00641318.async_wait
@asio|1461083709.062803|<28158494073611763|
@asio|1461083710.064992|>2|ec=system:0
@asio|1461083710.064992|2|deadline_timer@00641318.cancel
@asio|1461083710.064992|2*3|deadline_timer@00641318.async_wait
TimerHandler executed...
@asio|1461083710.065971|<28169626628843099|
@asio|1461083711.065223|>3|ec=system:0
@asio|1461083711.065223|3|deadline_timer@00641318.cancel
@asio|1461083711.065223|3*4|deadline_timer@00641318.async_wait
TimerHandler executed...
```

I actually did this test using only the header `TimerClass.hpp` (defining the methods directly within it -I was lazy-) and it worked like a charm, the problem seems to be when using the `.cpp` file, that's why I asked if you were using include guards (not the issue though, already tested).

---

You should consider changing your design approach though, i.e. do not use blocking loops in you handlers, just call another asynchronous operation if needed (like `async_read` or `async_write`).

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12238375/5583153) and corresponding accepted answer for a nice server implementation idea. Or try to adapt some of the [boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) to your needs.

As per the segmentation fault you get when separating declaration from definition in the corresponding header and implementation files, you might want to check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970935/segfault-with-asio-standalone-when-classes-in-separate-files).

Comment: Do you have an idea why it doesn't work with the .cpp? I'd rather not work with .hpp files exclusively.

Comment: @chrisp Yes, there is a problem with your socket pointers. No need to pass a `socket *` to the `TimerClass`, you only need the `io_service`. But I am still trying to fix the code in a fancy manner without changing your entire implmentation. Give me a few minutes

Comment: Hmm, I tried it using a socket pointer, socket reference, io_service pointer, io_service reference ... nothing seems to work. Also, what's wrong with the while loop? The timer is an async. event. Why would I need to remove the loop for it to work? I need it to process other events in my application. I guess I'll just wait for your solution.

Comment: You don't need the loop because you should use the asynchronous features of boost.asio: launch an `async_read` and within its handler launch an `asyc_write` for instance.

Comment: I have a queue that receives pushes on another thread. In the loop I start an async_write as soon as an element is found in the queue. I don't know how I should solve that without an infinite loop that looks for new elements in the queue. I guess I'll have to place the loop or timer on an extra thread.

Comment: @chrisp I edited my question with a few tips, unfortunately some work came up and I cannot provide any further assistance right now. Hope I could be of help.